# Список в списке SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-room

Есть две таблицы, получаю из них данные вот таким запросом:

```
SELECT *, covers.urlM AS coverUrls  
FROM vocabulary, covers 
WHERE covers.wordName = vocabulary.wordName
```

или

```
SELECT *, (
    SELECT covers.urlM 
    FROM covers 
    WHERE vocabulary.wordName = covers.wordName) AS coverUrls 
FROM vocabulary
```

Это две таблицы по типу один ко многим. В первой таблице (vocabulary): wordName - это PrimaryKey. Во второй (covers) используется для указания к которой записи в первой она относится. Но в них не используется ForeignKey для связывания этих таблиц.

P.S. SQL мало опыта и за такую конструкцию прошу не пинать, как-то случайно составил и оно работает.

**UPD:** пишу под Андроид, использую библиотеку Room. Должно получиться что-то на подобие:

```
Word1: Cover1.1
       Cover1.2
       Cover1.3
Word2: Cover2.1
       Cover2.2
       Cover2.3
```

Как я понимаю, это нужно будет делать отдельно ручками?

Comment: А можно более развернутый вопрос? Примеры таблиц со значениями?
Может быть просто у вас одно значение для wordName?

Comment: @radar4ick Изменил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте изменить запрос на более классический:

```
SELECT *, covers.urlM AS coverUrls  
FROM vocabulary JOIN covers 
ON covers.wordName = vocabulary.wordName
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает так же как и предыдущий. Я только что заметил свою ошибку. Оно работает но немного не так как мне нужно. Сейчас исправлю вопрос.